# Get the values from object wrapped in another object based on the key?

Tags: javascript, json, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to find the Javascript values of an object wrapped in another object based on the `Object Key` using the ES6 way or single-line approach without using the loop.

I have the `data` object something like this:

```
data = {
   "1":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"Identifiers",
      "data":{
         "ID":1,
         "nodeId":1,
         "eventType":"Identifiers"
      },
      "2":{
         "id":2,
         "name":"Events",
         "data":{
            "ID":2,
            "nodeId":1,
            "eventType":"ObjectEvent"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and I have a `connector` something like this:

```
{
   "ID":1,
   "name":"connector1",
   "source":"1",
   "target":"2"
}
```

I want to find the information from `data` based on the `connector.source`

I want to pass the `connector.source` and get the corresponding values from it, something like this:

```
"id":1,
"name":"Identifiers",
"data":{
        "ID":1,
         "nodeId":1,
         "eventType":"Identifiers"
      }
```

I am aware that I can use the `for loop` and do that but I am trying to find a ES6 way or using the single line code.

Comment: The ES6 way is also the ES5 way. `data[connector.source][connector.target]`? - Or do you not know at what depth the object will be?

Comment: Yup, this worked. The issue was with my `Vuex Store` which was not letting me modify outside the store. so modified that and this worked perfectly.